# How to handle dynamic error response in android using retrofit?

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit2

I am currently working on new android project with feathersjs back-end. Before error response normal format like,

```
     {
    "code": 123,
    "message": "An error occurred!"
  }
```

But now structure change dynamically according to the api request body. For Example I have three input field in my UI like Name, age, email after hitting api if wrong data error response will be like,

```
 {
    "code":123,
    "error":{
        "name":"Name is wrong",
        "age":"Age is greater than 18 is mandatory",
        "email:"Invalid email id"
    }
}
```

So I need to link Error response to correct Edittext Field and set Error Message. How I link this ?. But Request Body field name and error response field name are same.

Request Body structure :

```
    {

    "data":{
        "name":"xxx",
        "age":"24",
        "email:"xx@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Detail Explanation with Example Code will be more helpful.

Comment: make error response pojo and check when getting response that time check error class is not null then  get error message and show into edittext.

Comment: how i link error msg to correct editext. ex name error -> name edittext and age error --> age edittext

Comment: In Error pojo class has name age etc field getter or setter methods.

Comment: Hey that's right but if i have 100 field i need do write if condition like if(age!= null)etAge.setError(age)else if(email != null)etEmail.setError(email)......not good

Comment: @MageshPandian Are you using Rx with Retrofit?

Comment: only retrofit, may i know why ?

Comment: You can read `json array` for error and each field of json array. You can do this by comparing key in json array. Check if `key` is `name` then set error to name edittext

Comment: Yeah, because I had created kind of common error handling once with Rx and retrofit, but I believe the key concept should work for you too, let me try to find it out if I can.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir , Can you write piece of example in answer block with more detail. I am ready to upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Please post your code what you tried so far. I will make changes in that.